# Does Go have lambda expressions or anything similar?

Tags: go, lambda

Does Go support lambda expressions or anything similar?

I want to port a library from another language that uses lambda expressions (Ruby).

Comment: Go has [anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#Go), but not short function literals like `x -> x+1`.

Comment: A proposal for shorter anonymous function syntax in Go is under discussion since 2017: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21498

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Yes.

[Here is an example](http://livingcode.org/2009/11/13/go-language-and-functional-programming.html), copied and pasted carefully:

> ```
> package main
>
> import fmt "fmt"
>
> type Stringy func() string
>
> func foo() string{
>   return "Stringy function"
> }
>
> func takesAFunction(foo Stringy){
>   fmt.Printf("takesAFunction: %v\n", foo())
> }
>
> func returnsAFunction()Stringy{
>   return func()string{
>     fmt.Printf("Inner stringy function\n");
>     return "bar" // have to return a string to be stringy
>   }
> }
>
> func main(){
>   takesAFunction(foo);
>   var f Stringy = returnsAFunction();
>   f();
>   var baz Stringy = func()string{
>     return "anonymous stringy\n"
>   };
>   fmt.Printf(baz());
> }
> ```

Comment: I’d love to see more on your question than copied code. First and foremost, you could add a "yes"/"no"/"partly" etc. Then a bit of description, what your code actually does.

Comment: Kissaki basically he is passing functions to other functions and returning functions from functions, the code is self descriptive and th names are clever, takesaFunction receive a function than return string, returnsAFunction return a function than return a string.....so..yes...go support lambdas perfectly :D ....

Comment: One example that would be really nice to have in here is an example of a lambda function that takes an argument and is called in the same expression it's declared.

Comment: unfortunatly this example is confusing cause it is using the same name for a function (foo) and a parameter of another function (foo Stringy). I should have not been copied so carefully :)

Comment: Any reson  not to do 

 baz := func()string{ 
    return "anonymous stringy\n"
}

Comment: Why are there some semicolons in the main? Would that even compile against some version of a Go compiler?

Comment: I just note that `type` is not mandatory. You can directly declare `func takesAFunction(foo func()string)`

Answer (score 60):

Lambda expressions are also called function literals.  Go supports them completely.

See the language spec:
http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals

See a code-walk, with examples and a description:
http://golang.org/doc/codewalk/functions/

Comment: This is the best answer. I'd add that by "lambdas" people usually consider short function literals like `x -> x+1`, but Go doesn't support that kind of syntax, so you have to write the full `func (x int) { return x+1 }`.

Answer (score 20):

> **Yes**

In computer programming, an **anonymous function or lambda abstraction** (function literal) is a function definition that is not bound to an identifier, and **Go supports anonymous functions**, which can form closures. Anonymous functions are useful when you want to define a function inline without having to name it.

```
    package main
    import "fmt"

    func intSeq() func() int {
        i := 0
        return func() int {
            i += 1
            return i
        }
    }


    func main() {
       nextInt := intSeq()
       fmt.Println(nextInt())
       fmt.Println(nextInt())
       fmt.Println(nextInt())
       newInts := intSeq()
       fmt.Println(newInts())
    }
```

function intSeq returns another function, which we define anonymously in the body of intSeq. The **returned function closes over the variable i to form a closure**.

```
Output
$ go run closures.go
1
2
3
1
```

Comment: Taken word for word from https://gobyexample.com/closures

Answer (score 15):

The golang does not seem to make lambda expressions, but you can use a literal anonymous function, I wrote some examples when I was studying comparing the equivalent in JS!

#### no args return string:

```golang
func() string {
    return "some String Value"
}
//Js similar: () => 'some String Value'
```

#### with string args and return string

```golang
func(arg string) string {
    return "some String" + arg
}
//Js similar: (arg) => "some String Value" + arg
```

#### no arguments and no returns (void)

```golang
func() {
   fmt.Println("Some String Value")
} 
//Js similar: () => {console.log("Some String Value")}
```

#### with Arguments and no returns (void)

```golang
func(arg string) {
    fmt.Println("Some String " + arg)
}
//Js: (arg) => {console.log("Some String Value" + arg)}
```

Comment: Great answer, just missing example with auto run `()`

Comment: Go supports anonymous and higher order functions so it does let you "make lambda expressions". + 1 for example.

Answer (score 3):

An example that hasn't been provided yet that I was looking for is to assign values directly to variable/s from an anonymous function e.g.

```
test1, test2 := func() (string, string) {
    x := []string{"hello", "world"}
    return x[0], x[1]
}()
```

Note: you require brackets `()` at the end of the function to execute it and return the values otherwise only the function is returned and produces an `assignment mismatch: 2 variable but 1 values` error.

Comment: In Javascript, this pattern is called *Immediately Invoked Function Expression* (see [IIFE docs at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)), useful for hiding variables in modules, or changing scope of `var` variables.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a 'curried function' example. However the syntax seems unclear, relative to the lambda function syntax in other languages such as Swift, C#, etc.

```
func main() int { 
  var f func(string) func(string) int
  f = func(_x1 string) func(string) int { return func(_x2 string) int { return strings.Compare(_x1,_x2) } }
  return ((f)("b"))("a")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since it is a fully functional language, but has no fat arrow (=>) or thin arrow (->) as the usual lambda sign, and uses the **func** keyword for the sake of clarity and simplicity.