# Lambda Expressions in GO Language

Tags: go, lambda

In C#, we can write something like following using lambda expression, how can we achieve this in GO language? Basically, I am looking for an ability to pass some params to the function upfront and some params later when they are available.

```
myFunc = (x) => Test(123, x) // Method Test is declared below.
myFunc("hello") // this calls method Test with params int 123 & string "hello" where int was passed upfront whereas string was passed when Test is actually called on this line

void Test(int n, string x)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766320/does-go-have-lambda-expressions-or-anything-similiar).

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
func Test(n int, x string) {
    fmt.Println(n, x)
}
func main() {
    myFunc := func(x string) { Test(123, x) }
    myFunc("hello")
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/T6eNtGO8sWO)